# STATIC_ROOT in Django not working correctly

Tags: django

Trying to get static root set properly,

Went through the tango with Django tutorial and stuck on this part.

Basically this is my setting files, and the static folder is linked below in the tree.

```
C:.
├───media
│   └───locations
│       └───2018
│           └───11
│               └───11
│                   └───20
│                       └───18
├───Space
│   └───__pycache__
├───Spaces
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───static
│   ├───admin
│   │   ├───css
│   │   │   └───vendor
│   │   │       └───select2
│   │   ├───fonts
│   │   ├───img
│   │   │   └───gis
│   │   └───js
│   │       ├───admin
│   │       └───vendor
│   │           ├───jquery
│   │           ├───select2
│   │           │   └───i18n
│   │           └───xregexp
│   ├───css
│   └───images
│       └───parralax
│           └───home
├───templates
│   ├───registration
│   └───Spaces
└───users
    ├───migrations
    │   └───__pycache__
    └───__pycache__
```

and below you can see the settings i'm using for this .

```
"""
Django settings for Space project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)



BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '5a@tkcbah13t_vb!6pp6#z1c3j-3abb!&$6r-mw+%0mtzg$qo@'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'users',
    'Spaces',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Space.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media'
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,  ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR #where to look for files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' #where to serve files from on url
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Space.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/
```

essentially just want the root for static to be where i've put "static" in the directory.

Essentially I'm uploading to Heroku ATM, and I'm getting an error that it can't find the static root.

When changing my STATIC_ROOT to,

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,  ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR #where to look for files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' #where to serve files from on url
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Space.wsgi.application'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I get this issue :(

Comment: What is the problem? What is "not working correctly"?

Comment: Essentially I'm uploading to Heroku ATM, and I'm getting an error that it can't find the static root

Comment: But you don't seem to set STATIC_ROOT at all.

Comment: How would I set it to the appropriate folder?

Comment: Same way as you set anything else: `STATIC_ROOT = whatever`. Note there is no "appropriate folder", you need to just pick a name; `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')` is often used.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I got stuck on this - thank you

Comment: ?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting. Is the error I get when I set my root to the folder i'm using with staticfiles_DIRS.

Comment: I think I just need to set a new folder for my static_root

Comment: But then I don't see the point in having a normal static_dir